# delete duplicate rows from a table based on 1 column in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.3

I have to delete duplicate rows from a table based on 1 column. i.e. data is like

```
ruleid  action  ci_nodename
14      Allow   Database1
235     Allow   Database2
236     Allow   Database2
237     Allow   Database4
830     Allow   Database5
```

From this I want to remove duplicate rows based in ci_nodename column i.e. post removing data should be

```
ruleid  action  ci_nodename
14  Allow   Database1
235 Allow   Database2
237 Allow   Database4
830 Allow   Database5
```

I am using postgreSQL database.

Comment: So, here which row you want to keep, the minimum ruleid or maximum ruleid, or any of the ruleid will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

## To Identify the duplicate records based on criteria:

```
select ruleid,action,ci_nodename
from (
select  ruleid,action,ci_nodename,
        dense_rank() over(partition by ci_nodename order by ruleid) rn 
from your_table_name) s
where rn > 1
```

## To delete the duplicate records based on critaria:

```
delete from your_table_name
    where (ruleid,action,ci_nodename) 
       in (select ruleid,action,ci_nodename
    from (
    select  ruleid,action,ci_nodename,
            dense_rank() over(partition by ci_nodename order by ruleid) rn 
    from your_table_name) s
    where rn > 1)
```

Comment: If you find the information useful, accept the answer.